# jQuery: animate element position and opacity toghether

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, animation

I have div element with CSS style:

```
.somediv {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #4679BD;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

and I want to change div's position-top with jQuery animation. Also within this animation process I need to change opacity.

I tried to do it with this jQuery script:

```
$('.somediv').animate({
  'top':'150px',
  'opacity':'1'
}, 1000);
```

It works as I need in Firefox, but in Chrome position animation doesn't work. Div changes position immediately after animation complete.

**P.S:** If I change to `position:relative` then it works good in both browsers, but I need to do it with `position:absolute;`

**How to fix this?**

Here is the fiddle. Try in both browsers and you'll see the difference: **http://jsfiddle.net/eJXLf/**

.

**-----UPDATE-----**

This is how it looks in Chrome and Firefox:

**Chrome:**............................................... **Firefox:**

[image] ......................................
[image]

Comment: Works same for me Chrome as well as FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hard for me to test because I can't replicate it in my version of chrome, but you could try using marginTop instead?

```
$('.somediv').animate({
  marginTop: '150px',
  opacity: 1
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This method gave the result in all versions of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in Chrome 32.0.1700.76 for me. Both position and opacity animate smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is Chrome bug.

I used **Chrome 33.0.1750.46 beta-m** but when I tested in **Version 34.0.1812.0** it works ok.

Thanks for replies.